# Mapping a pentagon on a regular pentagon

Tags: geometry

It is nessecary for me to map a pentagon to a regular pentagon.

How could I do this, or where could I find this map.

For example by the following map, I could map a quadrilateral to a square.

$$N1(x,y) =\frac{1}{4}(1-x)(1-y),$$

$$N2(x,y) =\frac{1}{4}(1+x)(1-y),$$

$$N3(x,y) =\frac{1}{4}(1+x)(1+y),$$

$$N4(x,y) =\frac{1}{4}(1-x)(1+y).$$

where $x$ and $y$ are between $-1,1.$
The mapping can be achived by using these nodal shape functions

so $$a=\sum_{i=1}^4a_iN_i(x,y)$$
and $$b=\sum_{i=1}^4b_iN_i(x,y)$$
Here$a_i$and $b_i$ are the vertices coordinate of quadrilateral.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pentagon is convex, triangulate it using the barycenter and map this triangulation to one in the regular pentagon. Use barycentric coordinates.